# Rendering material-ui table vs HTML table [ ERROR: Element type is invalid]

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Why do I get the error

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

when using the material-ui Table component but not get the error when I used a simple HTML table or use the same Material-ui component elsewhere in my application?

[(Link to CodeSandbox with HTML table and commented out Material-UI Table)](https://codesandbox.io/s/yj9j28ppp1)

Answer (score 1):

Your material-ui imports are wrong (well, some are).

```
console.log(
  Table,
  TableHeader,
  TableHeaderColumn,
  TableRowColumn
);
```

These 4 are `null`. You'd have to import them differently (where did you find the last 3?).

You can import your components like this:

```
import {
  default as Table,
  TableBody,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableCell
} from 'material-ui/Table';
```

And fix your TableExampleSimple by using the correct components:

```
const TableExampleSimple = () => (
  <Table>
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Status</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
    <TableBody>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell>1</TableCell>
        <TableCell>John Smith</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Employed</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell>2</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Randal White</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Unemployed</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell>3</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Stephanie Sanders</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Employed</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell>4</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Steve Brown</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Employed</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell>5</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Christopher Nolan</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Unemployed</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </TableBody>
  </Table>
);
```

Updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/yq6ww61l0j

As a general tip, when you get "Element is invalid" error you can always start by checking your imported components. You can add this kind of debug code for each component:

```
if (!MyComponent) console.error("MyComponent's import is wrong");
```